# apt-get upgrade failed for libc locales

Tags: linux, ubuntu, package, sudo, apt-get

I have a server with 
`Linux version 2.6.32-042stab085.20 (root@rh6-build-x64) (gcc version 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Fri Mar 21 19:07:05 MSK 2014`

I always use apt-get update before upgrade, but lastly I am always getting error while upgrading:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6 : Breaks: locales (< 2.19)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

So I run with -f parameter and get this:

```
Preparing to unpack .../locales_2.19-11_all.deb ...
Unpacking locales (2.19-11) over (2.13+git20120306-12.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/locales_2.19-11_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/sbin/update-locale', which is also in package libc-bin 2.19-0ubuntu6.3
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/locales_2.19-11_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Somebody know how to repair it?

Comment: I recommend you ask this question on the Stack Exchange Ask Ubuntu (http://askubuntu.com/) site instead.

Comment: thanks. I will ask on this site then